# VSIX - Find TextUndoTransaction object that belongs to "Replace" action

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Is there a possibility to find the ITextUndoTransaction (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.operations.itextundotransaction.aspx) object, that belongs to a find-replace(all) action on an ITextBuffer? 
I have already looked at the CurrentTransaction property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.operations.itextundohistory.currenttransaction.aspx) in the ITextUndoHistory of the ITextBuffer where the replace action was applied to. But that property was always null in the Changing, Changed, ChangedLowPriority, ChangedHighpriority and PostChanged events, on the moment of the find-replace.
I think there must be a way to have access to the replace ITextUndoTransaction object, but how?

Comment: Can you add some sample code.  With the DTE objects casting is always a bit wonky, so it's possible you're not casting to the correct object.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll add some sample code tomorrow. What I try to do is fairly simple. After a find-replace via the UI, I see in the undo-toolbar menu, that there is a "Replace" undo-action added. Therof I want to have access to the undoprimitives of that transaction.

Comment: Undo in Visual Studio is a very complicated thing; what you want may not exist. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to synchronize the contents of some XML nodes (CDATA), with CSharp files in the same project. But undo-redo after find-replace, is messing things up.